# How does Creative interact with the first tier ability of Levity?

Tags: character-creation, the-strange, cypher-system

One of my players chose *Creative Spinner who Entertains* for his character. Now we are wondering whether the inability from *Creative* - "The diffilty of all tasks related to pleasant social interaction is one step higher for you" - cancels out the first Tier ability *Levity* ("You are trained in all social interactions other than those involving coercion or intimidation").

To me it feels like it should certainly be possible to be both creative and entertaining at the same time. On the other hand removing these inabilities could make things slightly "overpowered" (if there is such a thing in a story-centric game) or unbalanced.

Right now I'm thinking to make these bonuses more situational - e.g. more entertaining when in the spotlight but more creative when outside of it - but I fear that may make it difficult for the player to judge his abilities in any given situation and give too much room for arbitrary decisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both page 45 of The Strange Corebook and page 47 of the Numenera Corebook state

> If you become skilled at a task that you have an inability with, they
>   cancel out.

So I'd say that the end result of that rules interaction is that the player is not trained in social interactions that are pleasant or that involve coercion or intimidation. So they'd be trained in, for example, social interactions like bluffing.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. It's a bit unfortunate as in this situation it's the main aspects of *Creative* and *Entertains* that are effectively cancelling each other out.

Comment: In story, this could represent a natural problem the PC has and that she tempers with training. Bits of both sides could show up.